# How do I change this script to use a number to show content using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scroll

This is my code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var target = $(".passthis").offset().top-$(window).height();

    $(document).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= target) {
            $(".something").fadeIn(2000);
        }
    });


});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="passthis" style="text-align:center;font-size:20px;margin-top:815px;">

        Scroll Below here
    </div>
```

Right now this code will show div.something only when the user passes div.passthis.  The .passthis div is exactly at the bottom of the screen.  Howver, I want to move .passthis the middle of the screen but being new to JS i am unsure how i can modify my script to do that.  Can I use a number for x,y or something?

Question:

What can I do to move the .passthis to the middle of the screen and still make .something show after the user passes .passthis.

Comment: Just have a read of the docs for each function (`offset`,`height` and `scrollTop`) and it should be pretty simple to work out what you want to do

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/rcwgX/) that you are welcome to play with. As I explained, if the window never scrolls, nothing is going to happen (.something will never appear). Additionally, you can see the numbers for the different values in this demo. It should give you an idea of what you're shooting for as far as the MATH of it all is concerned. As recommended above, you should read up on jQuery's `.scrollTop()` and other window dimensional methods and values.

Comment: This didn't seem to work.  If i am not wrong the code is diviging the height by 2? Any other way I can do this?

Comment: My apologies, this will only change the position that causes the fadeIn. Where is the code that actually places `.passthis` on the screen? It might be using CSS.

Comment: Thanks  I tried but it didn't work perhaps because the scroll is not triggered?

Comment: Probably so. You just want the `.something` to appear when `.passthis` is moused over?

Comment: No, only when the user scrolls below it.  So that means i might have to push .passthis a bit below?

Comment: How can I hide the .something when the user scrolls back up above .passthis?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33137/discussion-between-devlshone-and-starbucks)